# Introductory differential equations problem: Boyce and DiPrima 1.1.17

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to revise my ODEs and I wanted to work out the kinks in my reasoning for this problem.
"A pond initially contains 1,000,000 gal of water and an unknown
amount of an undesirable chemical. Water containing 0.01 grams of
this chemical per gallon flows into the pond at a rate of 300 gal/h. The
mixture flows out at the same rate, so the amount of water in the pond
remains constant. Assume that the chemical is uniformly distributed
throughout the pond. Write a differential equation for the amount of chemical in
the pond at any time."

My reasoning is as follows (and having looked at an older post regarding this question, I'm still confused). There exists an initial amount $a$ grams that is in the water.
After 1 hour, there is an inflow of $3\text{ g}\;(0.01\text{ g} * 300 \text{ gal hr}^{-1})$.
During that one hour, since 3 grams have flowed in, the concentration is now $\frac{a+3}{10^6} \text{g gal}^{-1}$. Multiply that by the rate of outflow and you get $3(a+3)*10^{-4}\text{ g hr}^{-1}$. According to the answer, the outflow is  $3(a)*10^{-4}\text{ g hr}^{-1}$. Why is this the case? Does this have to do with the assumption that the chemical is uniformly distributed? If so, why?

Comment: Why do you assume that the outflow for the hour all  takes place at the end of the hour, after the inflow has mixed evenly?

Comment: Doesn't inflow affect outflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

It does not matter if we assume in the discretisation if the water flows out of the pond at the beginning or at the end of the time step because we will ultimately
take a limit $\Delta t\to 0\,.$ Nonetheless the method of thinking discretely
is the most efficient approach to derive the ODE:

Denote by

$A$ the amount of chemical in the water,

$V$ the volume of the pond,

$F$ the constant amount of water that flows in and out per time,

$\alpha$ the constant concentration of the chemical in the inflow $F\,.$

Since the concentration in the outflow is $A/V$ the amount of the chemical changes in one time step by
$$
dA=\alpha F\,dt-\frac{A}{V}F\,dt\,.
$$
This is an inhomogeneous linear ODE for $A(t)$ for which there are standard solution methods:

> \begin{align}A(t)&=e^{-\frac{F}{V}t}\Big\{A_0-\alpha V+\alpha Ve^{\frac{F}{V} t}\Big\}\\&=e^{-\frac{F}{V}t}\{A_0-\alpha V\}+\alpha V\,.\end{align}As it is intuitively clear, the amount $A$ tends to $\alpha V$ in the limit $t\to\infty\,.$ That is, the concentration of the chemical in the pond will ultimately be the same as in the inflow.