# How to motivate the teaching of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, education, math-history, motivation

I will have to teach a first course in differential equations. A good motivator might be to promulgate modelling with differential equations but I have seen some teachers have made polemic against modelling. Are there any really good resources on modelling with differential equations? I want something which will have an impact and motivate the learner. I am not really looking for artificial engineering examples but some bona fide real applications.
Also, would like to bring in some history of differential equations to motivate the learner.

Comment: What arguments are there against modelling?  Seems like the obvious way to motivate the field.

Comment: Modelling CAN be useful , but the model must be justified. We cannot use an arbitary model and hope it does the job , we must find out which model suitably describes the situation. Theoretical physics sadly made it the other way round. They started with complicated math and interprete everything how they need it so that it "fits" to this complicated math. This is not the right approach for physics.

Comment: Modelling is key I believe, and a very demanded skills in industry. You may want to highlight how modelling physical equation gives you tricks to model financial equations, etc. I believe the main point here is how you present the thing, if people believe and understand that it is useful although they will likely never have to solve this particular equation, you will get a lot of motivation.

Comment: I do not know the book mentioned in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4744986/949989) but it might be what you are looking for. To polemists against modelling: come forward if you have courage!

Comment: How about the old but gold Newton's law $F(x(t))=m x''(t)$? Or even something simpler, like "How do you find the trajectory $x(t)$ if I provide you with the velocity $v(t)$?" Physics is full of examples that can be used to motivate ODEs or PDEs.

Comment: [Epidemics modelling](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782522005345)? [Weather forecast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_numerical_weather_prediction)?